# cannot initialize webcam with my code (html /js/css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webcam

I am trying to make the ebcam work from my html and it won't work. The frames is there. But i cannot make it work. The webcam doesn't open and theres isn't even the pop up asking if I want to allow my wbcam to open....

am I missing something ? 
like  a plug-in to make it work ? o
or is there a mistake in my code ?

here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
</head>
<body>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js.js"></script>

<video id="video"></video>
<button id="startbutton">Take photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/150" id="photo" alt="photo">

</body>
```

here is the csss:

```
html {
    background: #111111;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient( #333, #000);
}
canvas {
    display: none;
}
video, img, #startbutton {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#startbutton {
    background: green;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 100px 20px 20px 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 880px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}/
```

here is the js:

```
// JavaScript Document
(function() {

  var streaming = false,
      video        = document.querySelector('#video'),
      cover        = document.querySelector('#cover'),
      canvas       = document.querySelector('#canvas'),
      photo        = document.querySelector('#photo'),
      startbutton  = document.querySelector('#startbutton'),
      width = 200,
      height = 0;

  navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia || 
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia);

  navigator.getMedia(
    { 
      video: true, 
      audio: false 
    },
    function(stream) {
      if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { 
        video.mozSrcObject = stream;
      } else {
        var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        video.src = vendorURL ? vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
      }
      video.play();
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("An error occured! " + err);
    }
  );

  video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
    if (!streaming) {
      height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth/width);
      video.setAttribute('width', width);
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      streaming = true;
    }
  }, false);

  function takepicture() {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
  }

  startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
      takepicture();
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

it does ask for access and display my webcam:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/e4Hf9/

don't know whats happening here, maybe you have a caching problem. try incognito / private browsing to your troubled page

Answer (score 0):

1. double check your code with the Mozilla's tutorial [Taking webcam photos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/taking_webcam_photos)
2. make sure your project has been correctly deployed on your server, like apache. and access your page via xx.xx.xx.xx:port/your_page

if you directly double click to open your code file, it won't work.